# Identify in ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop) does not show text in full length

Tags: arcmap, polygon, esri-geodatabase, text, identify

I have a *polygon feature* within an *ESRI-Geodatabase*. The field `TEXTFIELD` within this polygon feature is of type `Text` and of length `400`. A text within this field is visible in full length while editing the polygon feature as suggested in an [ESRI blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/mapping/how-to-extend-attribute-table-field-size-from-255-characters/). However, when requesting the content of any of the polygons with `identify`, only part of the text will show up. Please see example in the image: the text `----5---10---15 ... --390--395--400` has 400 signs. The result from identify shows `----5---10---15 ... --255--26` which are 259 signs. How can I make as many signs show up as there are in `TEXTFIELD`?

[image]

Comment: The HTML Popup tool is similar to Identify, but works only in Data View. You can control what the results look like, but it could be a lot of work.

Comment: Sounds interesting. However, I can not really follow what to do. In the end it should work for clients which will be the end-user of the product.

Comment: I don't believe you can alter the display length of the identity dialog. But to be frank a 400 character string is unreadable to most humans. What ever was generating that was not thinking of people and how they would comprehend the information. Not sure what value it is to anyone. Looking at your sample it steps up in steps of 5. If that is standard within the data may be a range is better, e.g. 0-260?